# Exception after calling a procedure of a package from another schema

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two schemas SCHEMA_1 and SCHEMA_2.

In SCHEMA_1, I have 2 tables, LOCATIONS and COUNCILS, with the following structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE SCHEMA_1.COUNCILS
   (    ID         NUMBER(*,0), 
    DCOUNCIL   VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
        CONSTRAINT COUNCILS_PK PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
   );
    
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA_1.LOCATIONS
   (    ID         NUMBER(*,0), 
    DLOCATION  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
        COUNCIL_ID NUMBER(*,0), 
    CONSTRAINT LOCATIONS_PK PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
    CONSTRAINT LOCATIONS_R01 FOREIGN KEY ("COUNCIL_ID")
    REFERENCES SCHEMA_1.COUNCILS ("ID") ENABLE 
   );
```

I also have, in SCHEMA_1, compiled one package, which includes a function to select the denomination of all locations inside a council:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SCHEMA_1.PAQ_LOCATIONS
IS

    TYPE t_TABLE_LOCATIONS IS TABLE OF LOCATIONS%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    
     FUNCTION OBTAIN_ALL
     (
     pe_council_id  IN COUNCILS.ID%TYPE
     )
     RETURN t_TABLE_LOCATIONS;

END PAQ_LOCATIONS;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SCHEMA_1.PAQ_LOCATIONS
IS

     FUNCTION OBTAIN_ALL
     (
     pe_council_id  IN COUNCILS.ID%TYPE
     )
     RETURN t_TABLE_LOCATIONS
     IS       
       CURSOR cur_locations
       IS
         SELECT *
           FROM LOCATIONS
          WHERE COUNCIL_ID = pe_council_id;

       v_tlocations t_TABLE_LOCATIONS;
       v_counter    BINARY_INTEGER;
     BEGIN

        v_counter := 0;
        FOR reg_location IN cur_locations
        LOOP
          v_contador := v_counter + 1;
          v_tlocations ( v_counter ) := reg_location;
        END LOOP;

        RETURN v_tlocations;
           
     END OBTAIN_ALL; 

   
END PAQ_LOCATIONS;
```

Then, I have granted execution privileges on "PAQ_LOCATIONS" to "SCHEMA_2".

```
PRIVILEGE  GRANTEE    GRANTABLE GRANTOR     OBJECT_NAME
EXECUTE    SCHEMA_2    NO   SCHEMA_1   PAQ_LOCATIONS
```

In "ESQUEMA_2", I try to execute "PAQ_LOCATIONS":

```
 DECLARE
    v_locations SCHEMA_1.PAQ_LOCATIONS.t_TABLE_LOCATIONS;
  BEGIN 
       
    v_locations := SCHEMA_1.PAQ_LOCATIONS.OBTAIN_ALL ( 6015 ); 

    FOR i IN v_locations.FIRST .. v_locations.LAST
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( v_locations (i).DLOCATION );
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Then it throws an exception:

```
"
Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :
  DECLARE
...etc...
  END;    

ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 27:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SCHEMA_1.PAQ_LOCATIONS' must be declared
ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 27:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: línea 5, columna 8:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: línea 5, columna 8:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: línea 7, columna 22:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: línea 7, columna 8:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
"
```

Comment: Hey,..your create table statement is wrong at first place. It has an extra `,`  after the foreign key constraint. Also you can minimize your code using bulk operation rather than looping it.

Comment: Thanks XING, I'll try iy, but the problem must be something about privileges. The same code runs ok when I execute it inside the SCHEMA_1.

Comment: It's impossible. Because the code you posted is having syntax error. Cannot run successfully. Please follow my suggestions and try once.

Comment: OK, the syntax error was due to trimming the structure of the table for reasons of simplicity. I added BULK COLLECT, and it returns the data faster, when the function is invoked from the schema itself (SCHEMA_1), but the problem of invoking the function from another schema still remains.

Comment: I finally found the problem. I assigned the execution privilege to the SCHEMA_2 user directly, instead of the role I had defined on SCHEMA_1. Thanks for your help.